# How hard is to begin develop for MS CRM after being good CiviCRM developer?

Tags: cms-integration

I know that MS CRM's platform is .NET and CiviCRM's PHP. Nevertheless we are looking for MS CRM developer with no result so I am wondering how hard it could be for somebody with knowledge od CiviCRM to develop for MS CRM.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

That is hard to answer :-). If I look with the perspective that developing for a CRM as being an integrated bit of software where a change can have impact on many levels, it should be roughly the same. And therefore not too difficult.

If I look from the perspective of it is just another programming language it is not too hard either. Personally I have developed in RPG400 (when I was still young and innocent), Visual Basic and now PHP/jQuery.

On the other hand, developing in an open source world where everyone is focused on sharing knowledge is a completely different ball game from developing in a closed source world where knowledge might be less easily shared can be very different.

Comment: Thank you a lot for answer. We are really struggling with this position so I am seeking any good advice. Do you know any CRM which is really similar to MS CRM and the learning should be smooth?

Comment: I have no idea, I know about CiviCRM :-) I have the feeling you have the wrong end of the stick here? You should select a CRM that fits your requirements and organization, not based on developers being available. As Xavier mentioned, you will find CRM developers hard to find anywhere.

Comment: I am only IT recruiter :D So my job is to find somebody who suits my clients wantings. Although he is so desperate that he is willing to hire anyone with some experience, but this guy has to know at least some similar CRM. But he is unable to tell me the exact specs, I guess cause he doesn't know even himself.

Comment: My reaction as a former IT manager if this would be your candidate is to not give you any more business in the future :-)

Answer (score 1):

Development is development, so switching from one language to another isn't that difficult, but...

It would be faster to start with someone knowing .NET and having her learning MS CRM than starting with someone knowing CiviCRM to learn .NET AND MS CRM.

Beside, finding civicrm developers is probably as hard as finding ms crm developers, so trying to convince one that is likely to be in high demand to give up on that knowledge and start learning a new CRM/language is probably not going to be that successful.

Good luck, finding good developers is difficult, no matter the language/software

Comment: Thank you a lot for answer. We are really struggling with this position so I am seeking any good advice. Do you know any CRM which is really similar to MS CRM and the learning should be smooth?

Comment: They are probably more similarities between two MS-whatever than between two wateverCRM, so find someone knowing MS products, give them a few hours before the interview so they can read the MS-CRM doc to know the name of the various concepts and components and if they are good, they can BS their way through the interview and learn on the job. If the sole requirement is "knowing a CRM", the process is probably not that well defined in the first place ;)